# SPOJ PALIN - Why is the mirroring approach guaranteed to give you the smallest palindrome larger than N?

Tags: algorithms, intuition, palindrome

https://www.spoj.com/problems/PALIN/

I am trying to understand the intuition behind why this algorithm actually works.

**Problem statement:**

Given a number $N\le10^5$ generate the palindrome just after it.

For example:

$613745$ => $614416$

**Algorithm:**

- Divide the number into 2 halves. Two halves because a palindrome's
  2nd half is the reverse of the 1st half.
- If the number is **even**, if the **rightmost** digit of the **left half** is **less than** the **leftmost** digit of the **right half** then **increment** the **left half** and **reverse** it to make the **right half**. Else if the **rightmost** digit of the **left half** is **greater than** the **leftmost digit** of the **right half** then just **reverse** the **left half** to make the **right half**.
- If the number is **odd**, then reverse the 1st half and make that reversed 1st half the 2nd half. Check if the number is greater than original input, if not increment the middle digit (adjust for carry) and try again.
- If equal just expand outwards.

Example for odd cases:

808 => 818

901 => 909

I understand how the algorithm works but I do not understand why it is guaranteed to give the smallest palindrome larger than $N$.

**What my intuition says so far:**

Since we are incrementing a digit that is present in the left half, we know that the value of the number will increase. Also if the left last digit is greater than the right first digit then we just copy over the reversed version of the left side, and thus limiting the increase of the number.

**But none of these steps explain why it is guaranteed to give the smallest palindrome larger than** $N$.

Is there a way to prove the correctness of the algorithm ?

Comment: Any other choice would require you to change some digit in the first half (or to change the final digit in the first half by more than $1$) and that would produce a larger number.

Comment: @lulu True, but how do you guarantee that number is smallest palindrome that is larger than the input ?

Comment: @lulu I mean how do you know we are not getting a palindrome which is larger than the smallest palindrome larger than the input.

Comment: For the reason I said.  If the early block matches then it has to be the same number.  If it doesn't match then your candidate number must be larger (since the early block essentially matches the starting number).

Comment: @lulu yes but if my candidate number is larger then how do I guarantee by just changing the middle digit that the number is smallest palindrome larger than the input

Comment: @lulu I am not sure I follow how this is obvious. Could you please elaborate a bit ?

Comment: I don't see the problem.  Consider the case where the number of digits is even. Look at the first half. First, you try to simply reflect it.  If that works it is clearly minimal  right?  Now, if it fails, then there is no palindrome that matches the first half.  Therefore, the first half of the answer must be greater than the first half of the original.  But we are only incrementing it by $1$, no other number of the same length is less than it (but still greater than the first half of the original) Now reflect and nothing can go wrong.  The odd length case is similar.

Comment: Note:  the way you wrote the algorithm is confusing.  The parity of the number is irrelevant.  The parity of the length of the number matters, of course.

Comment: Consider an example, $N=123456$.  The first half is $123$.  We flip that to make a palindrome, $123321$  That fails because $321$ is not bigger than $456$.  But this is the only palindrome of length six  that starts with $123$ so the one we seek has to begin with something greater than $123$.  $124$ is the least number greater than $123$ and $124421$ is a palindrome, clearly greater than the start.  No other palindrome could beat that one...lowering $124$ can't help.  So this must be the answer.